# Image View Scaling with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

I'm trying to scale the mode of an UIImageView, by default the value of the mode is `Scale to Fill`, in this mode my images seem to be stretched and doesn't look good, In `Aspect Fill` the images seem to be the best fit but when I'm in this mode the Image instead of staying 600 Width x 300 Height, it changes to a different aspect ratio, and it cover up all the data below the image. See the images below of reference:

- Size of the Image View

[image]

- *Scale to Fill Mode* all images are streched and cut off.

[image]
- *Aspect to Fill*, same picture but as you can see it's now much bigger in Height and it cuts off the top 2 cells leaving the remaining cells, but in some other images running the same mode the pictures look crisp and perfect.

[image] 
Any thoughts or suggestions on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try `Aspect fit`? Also, are you using Auto-Layout? If so, did you add constraints?

Comment: You can't fix this problem unless the image and the image view are the same size. It's the nature of image resolutions. Did you try aspect fit mode?

Comment: i tried Aspect Fit the image looks good but there's a chunk  of white space left on right hand side of the image and a third of the image is cut off @TeodorCiuraru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add constraints on UIImageView. Pin your UIImageView from top, bottom, left and right.

[image].

After adding constraints I would suggest to use "Aspect Fit" mode. The labels in bottom also need constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the constrains fixed my problem, but Aspect to Fit leaves blank spaces all around the image, Aspect Fill does the job for me here.